# Stuck on Python Fibonacci loop, only returns one value?

Tags: python, fibonacci

```
def GenerateFibonaci(x):

 if(x == 0):
  return 0

 elif(x == 1):
  return 1

 else:
    for i in range(x):
       return GenerateFibonaci(x-1) + GenerateFibonaci(x-2)

 print(GenerateFibonaci(x))
```

I'm attempting to write a program GenerateFibonaci(x) that takes one input and prints a listed fibonaci sequence depending on the length of x.

Here's what I get as an output, only one value instead of a list:

```
>>> GenerateFibonaci(6)
8
```

This is what I'm trying to get it to look like:

```
>>> GenerateFibonaci(5)
[0,1,1,2,3]
>>> GenerateFibonaci(8)
[0,1,1,2,3,5,8,13]
```

Not sure if I need to add a list statement or a new nested loop? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: may need a `while` loop and a list to append the fibonacci values.

Comment: @FishingCode That wouldn't be recursive.

Comment: A note on style: don't use upper camel case for function names, it makes them look like classes. And don't indent your code with just a single space, and be consistent in the number of spaces indented - 4 is standard and avoid many, many errors that just make you look silly. Apart from that: your example code always returns before printing and returns either a number or a sum of two numbers, so it makes sense you're not seeing a list. Specifically, your `for` loop returns on the first iteration. You could use `yield` and create a generator, if that's what you want.

Comment: Add function given below to your module
 and call print(p(GenerateFibonaci(30)))

If you want to change your function it has to handle lists instead of int it does now. Good Luck!


#this is comment. Code below.
def p(upto):
 olist=[]
 next=curr=prev=0
 olist.append(prev)
 if prev == upto:
   return olist
 else:
   curr=1
   next=curr+prev
   prev,curr=curr,next
   olist.append(next)
   if next >= upto:
     return olist
   else:
     while next < upto:
      olist.append(next)
      next=curr+prev
      prev,curr=curr,next
   return olist